# Error in creating status bar in PySide

Tags: python, pyside

While trying to create a status bar for my PySide Application, I recieved an error

`self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'statusBar'`

The code I used was `self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')` in the main class. The app is based on the examples mentioned in this [tutorial page](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/firstprograms/). Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call `statusBar()` on your `QApplication`, which does not possess such method.

You need to create a `QMainWindows` as your main widget, and call `statusBar` on it.
Have a look at the PySide documentation of [`QMainWindow`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QMainWindow.html). You'll find an example of how to use the status bar.